# Google Analytics on Checkout

Tags: pci-dss, vulnerability

Are there any risks to using Google Analytics on my checkout page? The page is on SSL and I will obviously be serving the analytics script from their secured URL.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to include a third-party script on any page that contains private data.

Answer (score 3):

Allowing any third party script to run on a page capturing user data means that third party could potentially capture any of the same data themselves. Whilst Google is *probably* safer than "random-site-x.com" on the web, you're still trusting that:

- They won't capture your users' personal information and bank details and let them leak
- They won't modify any of the data users are submitting in any way
- They aren't letting any sources modify their script before serving it to you
- They haven't let their server be compromised by some other third party
- Your user doesn't have any malware that may redirect Google requests elsewhere

Google are likely a bigger target than whatever website you're managing, so you're leaving a lot of trust in their hands to keep their script/servers at least as safe as your own website. You're also leaving a lot of trust in their hands to play nice with your customers' personal data.

Depending on your jurisdiction you may also be responsible for ensuring that you don't share certain customer data with third parties (e.g. certain interpretations of EU data protection laws), so you should consider if that applies to possibly sharing customer purchase data as well.

Comment: thanks that is much clearer. If I used the noscript version of the analytics that just uses a dynamic image would that mitigate these issues?

Comment: @CommerceArchitect have you considered respecting the (very little) privacy your users still have and simply not tracking their every move ? Plus, I really don't see the point of analytics on a checkout page.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I absolutely respect my customer's privacy. I am not trying to track an individual's behaviour. However, I do want to analyse how successful my checkout it as converting. So I can do something about it.

Comment: @CommerceArchitect giving Google the ability to see what your users are doing, what pages on your site they're visiting, and then keep and mine that data forever isn't what I call "respecting your customer's privacy". But nevertheless, even if that doesn't looke like an issue for you, this answer clearly explains why it's also a bad idea in terms of security.